# Sporadic crashes when trying to get application object

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, crashlytics

My app is reporting an occasional NullPointerException on the following line:

```
MyApplication.myAppInstance.updateDay();
```

from which I understand that myAppInstance is null. The above line is being called in the `onStart()` method of one of the app's main activity right below `super.onStart()`

In the application class I have:

```
public static MyApplication myAppInstance;
public MyApplication() {
    myAppInstance = this;
}
```

And that's the only place the variable gets written to in code.

The crash only happens on Android 9.

What would be causing this? The app kinda assumes that the application instance will always be available.

I should note that this crash only appears in the Play Console and not in Crashlytics.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3194)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3302)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1891)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7425)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.timSim.myScheduler.MainActivity.onStart (MainActivity.java:667)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1339)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:7392)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3157)
```

This is happening to a very small number of users, so I can't replicate it.

Comment: Did you specify an override of the Application class in your manifest?  If not, no such object would have been made.

Comment: This crash happens to a very small number of users, it works fine for 99.9% and the crash only happens on Android 9 so it's not some obvious mistake on my part.

Comment: MyApplication extends Application, right? Just to give more details

Comment: What does `MyApplication` look like and why are you using Singletons????????

Comment: Yes sorry, MyApplication extends `Application`

Comment: @Zun MyApplication class has 4000 lines of code and it's been working fine  for years for 99.9% of users and only has an occasional crash on Android 9. As for why singleton, who knows, the app is 3 years old. I'm sure I thought I had a valid reason. :-)

Comment: lol, I dislike seeing classes with more than 200 lines of code. You should consider reading about architectures, 4000 LoC is something to be ashamed of. Start reading here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/

Answer (score 0):

To use `Application` class. You need to declare it in the `manifests.xml`.

Try this:

```
 <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        .../>
```

And

```
class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // TODO:
    }
}
```

Comment: This crash happens to a very small number of users, it works fine for 99.9% and the crash only happens on Android 9 so it's not some obvious mistake on my part.

Comment: I see. What about devices? Is there any specific models? Any other certain phones that cause the problem?

Comment: It's specific to Android 9 and it's not limited to specific models/makes.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Have you checked this part? `java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.timSim.myScheduler.MainActivity.onStart`

Comment: Yes, that's the line `MyApplication.myAppInstance.updateDay();` that causes the NPE which means myAppInstance is null.

Comment: I don't know the whole class but, I guess it should be something like `MyApplication().getInstance().updateDay()`? or maybe just `MyApplication().myAppInstance.updateDay()`? Are you sure just calling `MyApplication`  without `()` is not `null`?